# Executing Zeppelin notebooks as recurring job in Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am migrating from Databricks to Amazon EMR and planning to use Zeppelin notebooks in place of Databricks notebooks. Currently, many of the Databricks notebooks are scheduled as jobs.  Is there any way how I can create recurring jobs or add Zeppelin notebooks to run as recurring step in Amazon EMR. Any reference to documentation will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [Zeppelin's built-in cron support](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/other_features/cron_scheduler.html) will meet your needs.

Comment: The problem here is that the cron scheduler will work in case of running clusters. If the cluster have to start everytime to run the job, what will be the ideal way.